# Using different widgets on the basis of value of spinner in flutter

Tags: flutter

I want the user on **Register** and **Login** screen to first choose their role from a drop down button and on the basis of its value I want to show further widgets on the very same page....
For this should i create a normal class containing all the respective widgets or a stateful widget?
and how to call that widget just after selecting the role from the DropDown List?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create different Stateful or stateless widget base on requirement for different role and you can change screen base on drop down value.

Following code will help you more.

```
class Delet2 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Delet2State createState() => _Delet2State();
}

class _Delet2State extends State<Delet2> {
  Widget _currentScreen;
  int role;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            _currentScreen ?? Container(),
            DropdownButton(
              value: role,
              items: [1, 2]
                  .map(
                    (item) => DropdownMenuItem(
                      value: item,
                      child: Text(
                        item.toString(),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                  .toList(),
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  role = value;
                  if (role == 1) {
                    _currentScreen = Screen1();
                  } else {
                    _currentScreen = Screen2();
                  }
                });
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Screen1 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Text("screen1"),
    );
  }
}

class Screen2 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Text("screen2"),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create Stateful widget and then based on the value selected in spinner you can draw widget, please follow below code snippet:

```
class MySpinnerWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MySpinnerWidgetWidgetState createState() => _MySpinnerWidgetWidgetState();
}

class _MySpinnerWidgetWidgetState extends State<MySpinnerWidget> {
  String dropdownValue = 'One';

  List<String> spinnerItems = ['One', 'Two', 'Three'];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(children: <Widget>[
          DropdownButton<String>(
            value: dropdownValue,
            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
            onChanged: (String data) {
              setState(() {
                dropdownValue = data;
              });
            },
            items: spinnerItems.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
              return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                value: value,
                child: Text(value),
              );
            }).toList(),
          ),
          if(dropdownValue == 'One')
            Text('Value One selected from spinner'),
          if(dropdownValue == 'Two')
            Text('Value Two selected from spinner'),
          if(dropdownValue == 'Three')
            Text('Value Three selected from spinner'),
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: @Kartik : Please accept the answer if it works for you.

Comment: I want to present a number of textfields after selection of the value of spinner so to do that I think i need different different classes instead of if statements. Thanks for the help man, really appreciate the effort.